# Menu Button on ViewPager toasts wrong position

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I am loading local htmls in webview using Viewpager. This works fine and the right page is loaded from the WebViewFragment into viewpager activity. Scroll or swipe works fine, but I added a menu button to get the title of the current webview, and to toast it. This menu button returns the webview title of the next 2 webview pages in the viewpager.

Reducing the setOfScreenLimit to 1 toasts the webview title of the next webview page in the viewpager. I cant setOfScreenLimit to 0. What is the most probable way to get the current item's webview title when the menu button is clicked. I need to get this and save to a DB.

Code:

ViewPager

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabsPagerAdapterEnglish pageAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapterEnglish(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int value = 0;
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getInt("keyHTML");
    }

    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(value);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapterEnglish extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3

    public TabsPagerAdapterEnglish(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return WebFragmentEnglish.newInstance(0, "file:///android_asset/page1.html");
            case 1:
                return WebFragmentEnglish.newInstance(1, "file:///android_asset/page2.html");
            case 2:
                return WebFragmentEnglish.newInstance(2, "file:///android_asset/page3.html");

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
     }

    }
```

WebFragment

```
public class WebFragmentEnglish extends Fragment {

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static WebFragmentEnglish newInstance(int position, String url) {
    WebFragmentEnglish fragmentFirst = new WebFragmentEnglish();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("page_position", position);
    args.putString("keyHTML", url);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    if (null != toolbar) {
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    }

    position = getArguments().getInt("page_position", 0);
    url = getArguments().getString("keyHTML");

    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    getActivity().finish();
                case R.id.action_addtofav:
                    webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                    htitle = webView.getTitle();
                    saveData();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), htitle + " added to favorite",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    progressBar.setMax(100);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo());
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.setLongClickable(false);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            progressBar.setProgress(progress);

        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error is in the controller implementation, or on ViewPager setup, but cannot confirm until seeing some code

Comment: @Chisko Thank you for your input. I have added code. Please check.

Comment: Another thing, if a button is pressed to toast the title from inside the layout inflated by WebViewFragment, it toasts the right title. but using the menu button toasts the tile of the next webview page. My thought is the menu button is controlled by the viewpager activity and so interfering in a way.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager will load the current page and the next page(s) up to the offScreenLimit. To get the name of the current page you need to get the current position of the adapter.

It's hard to give more specific help without having code posted. But you can use the ViewPager getCurrentItem method to get the visible index. From there you can either compare it to the index of the page you're displaying (this works if the view pager is static and pages are known in advance), or you can use that index to get the Fragment from the PagerAdapter and call a method on it to save the name.

Comment: Thanks, code has been added @Ben. if a button is pressed to toast the title from inside the layout inflated by WebViewFragment, it toasts the right title. but using the menu button toasts the tile of the next webview page. My thought is the menu button is controlled by the viewpager activity and so interfering in a way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the ViewPager.

I removed the toolbar instance from the fragment to use the one in the viewpager's activity. Then in my options menu, you would notice I used

```
webView = (WebView) **getActivity().**findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

I removed the this completely, since i have already defined it in the onCreateView, I think maybe its because of the getActivity field I added to locate the webview ID.

I was updating an old code, I'm glad I was able to solve this. Thank you @Chisko and @Ben